# How to protect outside access?

Tags: spring-mvc

How protect resouces from outside access in the Web application using jsp - spring  ?

e.g.
http://localhost:8080/appsname/images/ 
here showing list of files

here i dont want to users to direct access to my image folder.if any one trying to do then redirect to error page or home page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it is to store the images somewhere outside the web container (Tomcat?) like in /opt/data/webapp_name/images/ and write a controller that retrieves the images from that locations. Thus there is no direct access to the images and all kinds of security logic can be added to the controller.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this is achieved by configuring your webserver to disallow directory browsing on a particular directory. For example, using the apache webserver, you'd use `Options -Indexes`